# Duplicating smoke simulation result for still image

Tags: cycles-render-engine, smoke-simulation

I have a still scene which is lit by about 100 or so torches and so I created a basic smoke/fire simulation for one of them using the quick smoke effect. I've found a frame which I'm happy with and now I want to use this frame for all these torches. Obviously I can't have a scene with 100 smoke simulations if I want it to render this side of the century so I was hoping to be able to "duplicate" this single frame of simulation in a similar way as you would duplicate a mesh and then position it over all the torches.

I've had a go at baking the simulation but I am at a loss for how to actually go about duplicating it across to my multiple torches. Is this actually possible to do or is there a much easier way of having multiple fires in a single scene? They're quite far away so they don't have to be particularly high res. I'm using cycles.